# Как сократить код (slideshow смена изображения)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, setinterval

Как сократить данный участок кода? Знаю есть решение, не мой мозг никак не может его придумать.

```
$("#slideshow > a:gt(0)").hide(), setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#slideshow > a:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo("#slideshow")
}, 1e4), 

$("#slideshow2 > a:gt(0)").hide(), setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#slideshow2 > a:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo("#slideshow2")
}, 1e4), 

$("#slideshow3 > a:gt(0)").hide(), setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#slideshow3 > a:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo("#slideshow3")
}, 1e4), 

$("#slideshow4 > a:gt(0)").hide(), setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#slideshow4 > a:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo("#slideshow4")
}, 1e4), 

$("#slideshow5 > a:gt(0)").hide(), setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#slideshow5 > a:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo("#slideshow5")
}, 1e4), 

$("#slideshow6 > a:gt(0)").hide(), setInterval(function() 
{
    $("#slideshow6 > a:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo("#slideshow6")
}, 1e4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```
for (var i=0; i<=6; i++){
 (function(i) {
  $("#slideshow"+i+" > a:gt(0)").hide(), setInterval(function() {
    $("#slideshow"+i+" > a:first").fadeOut(0).next().fadeIn(0).end().appendTo("#slideshow"+i)
  }, 1e4);
 })(i); 
}
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, добрый человек!